# How can I paginate this BigQuery query using the rownumber?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can this BigQuery query be updated to allow for the additional clause for pagination?

```
SELECT test.id, test.city, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rownumber FROM prod.test LEFT OUTER JOIN prod.locations AS location ON (test.city = location.id)
WHERE active = true 
AND rownumber BETWEEN 10000 AND 30000
```

The resulting error is:

> Unrecognized name: rownumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this example, use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT test.id, test.city, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rownumber
      FROM prod.test LEFT OUTER JOIN
           prod.locations location
           ON test.city = location.id
      WHERE active = true
     ) t 
WHERE rownumber BETWEEN 10000 AND 30000 ;
```

However, you should probably be using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use CTE

```
with cte as
(
 SELECT test.id, test.city, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rownumber 
 FROM prod.test LEFT OUTER JOIN prod.locations AS location ON (test.city = location.id)
WHERE active = true
 ) select * from cte where rownumber BETWEEN 10000 AND 30000
```

rownumber  is a inline alias which not supported in where clause directly

Answer (score 1):

You can use this standard sql clause if bigquery supports it,

```
SELECT 
       test.id
      ,test.city
FROM prod.test as test 
LEFT OUTER JOIN prod.locations AS location ON (test.city = location.id)
    WHERE active = true
order by test.id
offset 10000 rows fetch next 20000 rows only
```